# Proper edge coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is the edge chromatic number of an odd sized clique equal to $\Delta+1$, where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree? For a triangle this is obvious, so I tried to proceed by induction on the number of nodes and failed. Thanks in advance.

By Vizing theorem we know, every graph can be edge properly colored in either $\Delta$ or $\Delta+1$ cf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing%27s_theorem

Comment: Hint:For a complete graph of $2n+1$ vertices, suppose the edge chromatic numbers is $2n$. Then show that each vertex has 1 edge that is (say) red? How many red edges are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing Calvin Lin's thought that if the edges of a complete graph $G$ of order $2n+1$ are correctly colored in $2n$ colors, then exactly one edge of each color comes out from each vertex of the graph.

Let us fix some color, say red. Now remove from the graph $G$ all edges except the red one. The degree of each vertex of the new graph is $1$. But then the new graph is a perfect matching with odd number of vertices. Contradiction.